# Solicitar preenchimento de campo na url

Tags: php, html, ajax, url

Boa tarde...

Preciso de uma ajuda de vocês. Eu tenho uma página em html+php que basicamente é um campo que consulta um banco mysql com ajax e retorna o resultado assim que é preenchido o campo com a quantidade correta de números (10 algarismos).

Eu queria fazer uma solicitação através da URL para já carregar a página com este campo preenchido. Por ex... Quando eu digito [google.com.br/?q=pergunta](https://www.google.com.br/?q=pergunta) o Google abre com o campo escrito "pergunta"

Como eu faço isso? Eu tenho que marcar meu campo e definir esse "q"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que seja isso que procuras:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['q'] ?>" />
```

Supondo que a URL seja: `seusite.com/?q=string`

O resultado com `$_GET` no exemplo acima seria:

```
<input type="text" value="string" />
```

> Se o `input` for `type="number"`, só irá receber números pelo `$_GET` (ex., `q=123456`).
>   Se for `type="text"`, irá receber qualquer string (tanto de números
>   como de letras).

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Insira o script abaixo no seu código-fonte. Ele irá chamar a função caso o `$_GET` retorne algum valor:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['q'])){ ?>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('inputid')[0].blur();
  },1);
};
</script>
<?php } ?>
```